# Kitchen/Workshop unit design

Tags: cabinetry, boxes, drawer, carcass

I'm wanting to add some storage and organisation to my workshop shed and my initial idea was to basically build some frameless kitchen units.

My depth will be 400mm and my total available length is 2m.

I was thinking for ease of building, I might do 2 x 1m long units, however I would like a drawer at the top with 2 doors below. a 1m long drawer seems a little drastic, and might not stand up to the amount of weight I put in them... So 2 x 500mm drawers might be preferrable.

A couple of questions - How would one go about splitting a 1m long unit to have 2 500mm drawers? Would it be easier to just create 4 x 500mm units?

Comment: Why did you delete the bookcase Q? You only needed to edit it down to the first query.... which I was in the middle of writing an Answer to :-)

Comment: @Graphus You told me to break it into two... Undeleted.

Answer (score 2):

1 meter drawers are pretty wide -- they could work, but would have to be substantial.

If you split the 1m unit into 2 bays for drawers, you could insert a full width shelf below the drawers and have a short upright gable between. You could also hang the drawer glides from the underside of the top, though that could get complicated.

Having said that, making 4 smaller units has its merits: they're easier to handle and install solo. On the downside, you'd use a bit more material and it would take a little longer.

Comment: How would one go about splitting the 1 long drawer into 2? I would have a horizontal stretcher to split the drawer sectio from the door section as to give the doors something to close against... But how to add a divider for slides to attach to? Looking at an existing product on the market (https://kitchenbedroomdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Drawerline-Double-Dresser-Unit-with-Drawers-White-Square-Swatch-768x768.jpg) it seems I can do some pocket holing to add some stretcher front to back.

Comment: I think I like this style a bit more: http://www.greenheartkitchens.co.uk/image/cache/data/products/base-units/double-drawerline/front-open-700x700.jpg so it will be a horiontal stretcher with a short vertical stretcher and the same design with the front to back piece.

Comment: You don’t need a full-height piece splitting the cabinet. And it’s not clear what’s going on in the second image. Let me know if you want a sketch.

Answer (score 2):

> however I would like a drawer at the top with 2 doors below. a 1m long drawer seems a little drastic

A 1m wide drawer is perfectly doable if you have the confidence to build one. Think about wide plan chests with their full-width drawers built in the days before modern power tools....

However, with modern construction methods experienced builders warn that it's difficult to make and install very wide drawers so that there are no sticky points.

> a 1m long drawer seems a little drastic, and might not stand up to the amount of weight I put in them

Well how much weight were you planning on loading into it?

You're presumably building from plywood, MDF or chipboard/particleboard, standard for frameless cabinetry. Even using the poorest of these materials (as certainly was common in Europe until recent years) one sizeable drawer in many kitchen installations can hold all a family's saucepans, along with a number of cast-iron pans to boot. Even basic Ikea drawers can have a weight rating of ~55lb (25kg)!

If you build/engineer the drawer box properly I'm sure that'll handle the weight no problem, the real limiter is *the weight capacity of the slides*, with their related cost<sup>1</sup>.

> Would it be easier to just create 4 x 500mm units?

Depends on your definition of easier.

This is really subjective. That's a ton more cutting, and some will want to reduce the number of cuts (e.g. because of the risk of introducing errors, more actual work to put together) in the same way that others would prefer to reduce the length of cuts (e.g. perhaps due to lower confidence in their TS skills).

For others neither of those are any limitation because they've worked through their *amount of effort required = ugh* issues :-) and can have table saw outfeed set up to easily handle longer rips (or, an assistant), along with featherboards or other hold-in/hold-down devices set up to help ensure accuracy.

Perhaps the limiting factor here is the total weight of the carcass if you have to install them solo. Certainly 1m wide cabinets can be heavy, and a box that size is always unwieldy; but what are most commonly called French cleats can do a lot to ameliorate this, since you just lift straight up and once over the lip you lower it and you're pretty much done.

---

Regardless of your level of gumption bear in mind how much interior space is lost to the double walls between cabinets. Even for 1/2" material, which almost nobody uses<sup>2</sup>, it's a full 1" for each junction..... using 3/4" material in total you're going to lose something like 4 1/2" o_O

---

<sup>1</sup> Both reasons I would be temped not to use metal drawer slides at all and instead go old-school and use hardwood runners.

<sup>2</sup> Although its use should be more common because it can be perfectly suited to many applications where 3/4" is unthinkingly chosen. Plus it can be noticeably cheaper. And of course it's lighter. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=en48E7UVzzc) is the Honest Carpenter talking about it.